# Checking if a method is set

Tags: java

"a fourth field to keep track of whether or not the alarm is set; alternatively, you could set the alarm fields to a negative value (-1 is my favorite)." Please help, I am trying to create a field which checks if my method is set. I've tried an if and statement so far but it probably is not the way to go. I need to check that my alarm is set. Probably going to need a return value then right?

```
public void setAlarm (int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
    if(hours minutes seconds > 0) {
        alarmHour = hours;
        alarmMinute = minutes;
        alarmSecond = seconds;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Please set the alarm.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what is intended.

```
private boolean isSet;

public boolean isAlarmSet()
{
    return isSet;
}

public void setAlarm (int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
    alarmHour = hours;
    alarmMinute = minutes;
    alarmSecond = seconds;
    isSet = true;
}
```

Comment: I love you, how did you get so smart in code and how do I get that good? :(

Comment: @BrandonWhite Experience. You need to write a lot of code, read a lot (blogs, books, articles) on how to get better, and find people to learn from.

Comment: Though don't read too much about _how_ to get better. Focus on reading code and such (architecture/design etc)  :)

Comment: Thanks, this is my first couple of weeks in Software engineering (major), I am pretty good but when I get stuck I do not know where to look for resources so I just ask. Can you recommend any good blogs or websites with good articles? I want to read more about programming. Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend [javalobby](http://java.dzone.com), and the book _"The Pragmatic programmer"_. I've seen others recommend _"Code Complete"_ and _"Clean Code"_, but I haven't looked into those myself. If you're a beginner you might want to start with something simpler though.

Comment: @Keyser those are all good resources, I heartily recommend them.  The other thing I would look at it the Gang of Four book on patterns, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns

Comment: @BrandonWhite I would also recommend http://www.amazon.com/Test-Driven-Development-Kent-Beck/dp/0321146530

Comment: I'll start with the easiest ones since I am only a noob aspiring to be great but thanks a lot for the help, hopefully I'll be helping someone else in a few months!

Comment: If you're aspiring to be great you really need to check out Donald Knuth's _"The Art of Computer Programming"_ at some point. He's one of the great ones.

Comment: lol So should I start with that one? I'll read the website daily but I can only read one book at a time.

Comment: No you really shouldn't :) You can, but you shouldn't. Start with some intro-to-java thing perhaps. Then get into design patterns, algorithms and such, then learn a bunch of other languages. This is just me talking though :p I'm also a novice. Good luck!